# How can I parse a JSON string into a struct in swift?

Tags: json, swift

Here's the code I have so far:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    func readStream() {
        // AF is the AlamoFire library
        AF.streamRequest("https://example.com/stream/\(streamId)", headers: [.authorization(bearerToken: API_TOKEN)]).responseStreamString { stream in
            switch stream.event {
                case let .stream(result):
                    // this is where I want to parse the result JSON string into a struct
                    print(result)

                case .complete:
                    print("Stream ended, starting new request to continue reading data")
                    self.readStream()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API I'm working with expects the client to open an HTTP connection, and then read events which come in as JSON strings—one per line.

So far, I've done a bunch of Googling, for things like "JSON String to struct". I learned that I need to set up a `Decodable` struct which matches my expected format for the `result` JSON string. But I'm stuck on how to convert the JSON String into that struct:

```swift
struct StreamUpdate : Decodable{
    var timeElapsed: Int
    var totalSum: Int
    var medianSoFar: Int
}
```

I've tried to use JSONDecoder, by replacing `print(result)` with:

```swift
let parsedJson = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StreamUpdate.self, result.get())
```

This was recommended by Raildex in a comment and seems supported by [these Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder). But it causes an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

Comment: Instantiate a `JSONDecoder` and decode your string with it

Comment: @Raildex When I do that, I get the following error: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'". I've updated the question with what I tried.

Comment: Ah, it looks like instead of `result.get()` which is a string, I need to pass `try result.get().data(using: .utf8)` which is a "Data". Not really sure what that is, but it seems to work. thanks for the help.

Feel free to post as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: en parsed json you have to pass object of type data, maybe result.get is string.

Comment: All Decoders take a Data object. you can use String.data() to get the data of your string

Comment: The method is `decode(_:from:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode There is no `from`, and the `from` parameter expects a `Data` instance, not a `String` one.